# Xcode 7.0 updated twice in Mac Appstore

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I was updating to Xcode 7 but in my case I had to install two separate updates from the Mac AppStore.  Both updates are labeled as Xcode Version 7.0.  However the first update was about 2GB and second update was about 4GB.  After installing the first 7.0 update, launching Xcode shows it was still running at 6.x level.  Did anyone else have the same experience?  Is there any reason for concern that one of the update was [illegitimate](http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2015/09/novel-malware-xcodeghost-modifies-xcode-infects-apple-ios-apps-and-hits-app-store/)?

[image: screenshot from the Appstore after installing both 7.0 updates]

Answer (score 0):

Apple has released this [memo](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09222015a) to developers today:

> To verify the identity of your copy of Xcode run the following command
>   in Terminal on a system with Gatekeeper enabled: spctl --assess
>   --verbose /Applications/Xcode.app
>
> where /Applications/ is the directory where Xcode is installed. This
>   tool performs the same checks that Gatekeeper uses to validate the
>   code signatures of applications. The tool can take up to several
>   minutes to complete the assessment for Xcode.
>
> The tool should return the following result for a version of Xcode
>   downloaded from the Mac App Store: /Applications/Xcode.app: accepted
>   source=Mac App Store
>
> and for a version downloaded from the Apple Developer web site, the
>   result should read either /Applications/Xcode.app: accepted
>   source=Apple
>
> or
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app: accepted source=Apple System
>
> Any result other than ‘accepted’ or any source other than ‘Mac App
>   Store’, ‘Apple System’ or ‘Apple’ indicates that the application
>   signature is not valid for Xcode. You should download a clean copy of
>   Xcode and recompile your apps before submitting them for review.

According to the above test, I do have a legitimate version of XCode 7.